# Grouping in Linq with TimeSpan.Hours

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datatable

I have a datatable that has following columns

```
CallTime   CallType

15:45:00    Voice
15:30:54    Voice
00:12:14    SMS
01:13:47    Voice
05:48:23    SMS
12:00:47    Voice
```

Now what i want Using Linq Result Like This

```
Hrs   Count
00    1
01    1
02    0
03    0
04    0
05    1
06    0
|
|
|
12    1
13    0
|
15    2
16    0
|
|
23    0
```

I am using Following query that gives me values having count > 0 but i wanna get those also having count = 0

```
var groupQueryTimeTotal = (from r in Foundrows.AsEnumerable()
                                   let time = TimeSpan.Parse(r.Field<string>("Call Time"))
                                   group r by time.Hours
                                       into g
                                       select new
                                       {
                                           CallTime = g.Key,
                                           CallCount = g.Count(),
                                       }).OrderBy(s => s.CallTime);
```

This query giving me result like

```
Hrs   Count
00    1
01    1
05    1
12    1
15    2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perform a [Grouped Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397905.aspx) where the first collection is `Enumerable.Range(0, 24)` and the second collection is `Foundrows.AsEnumerable()`.

*Example:*

```
var input = new List<TimeSpan>
{
    new TimeSpan(15, 45, 00),
    new TimeSpan(15, 30, 54),
    new TimeSpan(00, 12, 14),
    new TimeSpan(01, 13, 47),
    new TimeSpan(05, 48, 23),
    new TimeSpan(12, 00, 47),
};

var query = from hour in Enumerable.Range(0, 24)
            join item in input on hour equals item.Hours into g
            select new
            {
                CallTime = hour,
                CallCount = g.Count(),
            };

foreach (var x in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0:00} {1}", x.CallTime, x.CallCount);
}
```

Comment: +1 I didn't know Enumerable.Range existed before!  Thanks - I've always wanted a method like that!

Comment: What should i give in On Keyword here for left outer join

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ought to work:

```
var groupQueryTimeTotal = 
  Enumerable.Range(0, 24).Select(h => new { CallTime = h,
  CallCount = Foundrows.AsEnumerable()
  .Count(r => TimeSpan.Parse(r.Field<string>("Call Time")).Hours == h), });
```

That's really inefficient of course, parsing the same strings many times. Here's a different approach:

```
var groupQueryTimeTotal = new int[24];
foreach (var r in Foundrows)
{
  int hour = TimeSpan.Parse(r.Field<string>("Call Time")).Hours;
  ++groupQueryTimeTotal[hour];
}
```